# Overwrite Rails validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you overwrite a validation message in Rails?
Even if I pass in a proc like so..

```
validates :my_item, uniqueness: {
      scope: [:name, :type],
      message: -> (object, data) do
        "This item is already taken"
      end,
    }
```

It still appends the [object] to the front of the message. So that is reads: `"[name of the object] This item is already taken"`

Edit:

Also have tried adding a `^` to the beginning of message. Still does not work.
`"^This item is already taken"`

Comment: Are you talking about `full_messages` because the errors `Hash` will look like `{my_item: ['This item is already taken']}` and `full_messages` will map the key with each value creating `"my_item this item is already taken"`. Where are you having the actual issue?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to override it at the model level, just leverage the fact that you're essentially trying to tweak the `en` locale.

In `config/locales/en.yml` you should be able to do something like this:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "This item is already taken."
      models:
        my_item:
          taken: "This item is already taken."
```

I haven't tested this config directly, but the `messages` key should change the message for all models. Otherwise you can specify the message on a per-model basis. I don't believe that this will include the object name. You can find a list of the field names in the [Rails Internationalization Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation).

Comment: ^ This. You might think 'hey, I'm not trying to translate things', but I18n is the right solution for doing what you need. This keeps the strings out of the codebase, and makes it easy to make changes.